# Copy only the nodes where the name contains "a"

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an asigment that basically read like this :

I have this XMl structure

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="monfichier.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<a>
<ab x="x"><b>Test</b><a>z</a></ab>
<z x="x"><a>z</a></z>
</a>
```

And I need to copy all node where the name contains "a" but where the parent also contains an "a". In my example, that would mean skipping the node

```
 <z x="x"><a>z</a></z>
```

Since the parent's name contains "z" and not "a". Here is what my output should look like.

```
<a>
<ab x="x"><a>z</a></ab>
```

This assignment is a two part one, the first part is to write XSLT code that do not uses xsl:element and the second which won't use xsl:copy. I'm still at the first part, so xsl:copy is okay.

Here is what I've come up with, looking around the internet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(), 'a')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that this code does not ignore the  node... I can't seems to get my head around this.

Thank you

**EDIT**

With Potame's anwser I was able to figure out the second part of the assignment, which is to do the same thing without any xsl:copy.

Here is the code, it works like a charm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'a')]/*[contains(name(), 'a')] | /*[contains(name(), 'a')]">
     <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@x">
           <xsl:attribute name="x" >
             <xsl:value-of select="@x" />
           </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*" >
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Save yourself and find another way.  XSLT is nuts.  XPATH a little better.  JSON is proper.  jQuery has means to do this type of thing, right?

Comment: "*where the parent doesn't contains anything else than a*": is `<aaa>` OK? Do we have to differentiate 'A' and 'a'? Moreover, when you need to skip an element, do you still have to process children?

Comment: @RonRoyston I can't, I would gladly use Jquery or anything else, but the assignment specifically asks for Xlst.

Comment: @potame Yes, as long as there is a "a" in the name it could be anything, even the word anything. I did not state this well, I meant that the parent must also contains a "a", I will edit.

Comment: Go here and ask.  Michael Kay himself will likely answer you.  XSL-List: The Open Forum on XSL <xsl-list-service@lists.mulberrytech.com>

Comment: Have you tried this: `<xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(), 'a') and contains(local-name(..), 'a')]">`

Comment: It's better, but it still takes the text from the "b" nodes and forget the attribute from the "ab" node. It creates this : <ab>Test<a>z</a></ab>
z

Comment: Confused: The top-most <a> node in your example should not be copied, since the name of its parent (the document node) does not contain 'a'.

Comment: This is because of how you copy/apply templates you should do `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*" /><xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(local-name(), 'a')]"/></xsl:copy>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small stylesheet that will lead you to the expected result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'a')]/*[contains(name(), 'a')] | /*[contains(name(), 'a')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I think it's not really clearly stated for the case of the text within an element that has to be skipped.

Morover, how should we process such a case:

```
<a>
  <z x="x">
    <aa>z
      <ade>Another case</ade>
    </aa>
  </z>
</a>
```

`<z>` is to be skipped, but should we do to his contents? Regarding your rules, `<ade>` should be output because it a child of `<aa>`, but `<aa>` is not processed at all because its parent is `z` (skipped).

Comment: It work perfectly! Since it is an assignment, even I don't know what to do in the case presented, the only thing I had to do was understand how to do it for this particular case. That way I understand your code is that you check if any first, second and third child all contains "a" with a 0 to many match... Do I understand it well?